# GUI on ubuntu randomly stops working

Tags: command-line, gui

I was working on Ubuntu (Dual booting Ubuntu and windows) and i was installing python when i found out that the web browsers icon had disappear. After that happened i also found out that I couldn't open terminal any more and also some other apps like Ubuntu store. I decided to restart my PC and I booted into Ubuntu and it showed the loading screen but then i get greeted with a terminal and I cant manage to enable the GUI.

Cheers

Comment: *"i was installing python"* how exactly? python is already installed on Ubuntu out of the box, and parts of the system depend critically on it - messing with the default version can cause serious problems

Comment: sudo apt-get install python3 or something like that

Comment: I uninstalled it and reinstalled it

Comment: If so how can i fix it?

Comment: If you just (re)installed the default version of python3 from the repository then that shouldn't have harmed anything - we will need to look elsewhere for the problem

Answer (score 0):

Please check, if the **gdm-service** is running:

```
sudo systemctl status gdm
```

(This service handles graphical user logins.)
If not, try to start it with following command:

```
sudo systemctl start gdm
```

Now you should at least be able to log in into GNOME.
If so, open up a terminal (if possible) and enable the gdm service, that you don't have to start it manually at the next boot:

```
sudo systemctl enable gdm
```

Comment: When i boot it goes straight to a terminal and prompts me for login and password. Ill check that your answer work

Comment: I did "sudo systemct1 status gdm" and it wasnt recognized as a command or program

Comment: Sorry, should have asked earlier: Which Ubuntu version are you using?